# Titanium: Alert Onload

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

Is it possible to display an alert instantly after a window has loaded?

I have a create window statement then an alert message, then return.

```
function NewView() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
    alert("Will display a basic alert, maybe confirm alert");
    return self; 
}
```

When this is fired the alert displays but is overlapped with the background of the window. I have tried to make the background window 'transparent' this didn't make a difference.

Any help would be great, I feel it is a simple task just not thinking it through....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Just use the `open` event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-open) of the window, it is fired when the window is opened. Just make sure to add the listener before yo actually open the window.

Modify your code like this and it will open the alert when the window is opened:

```
function NewView() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
    self.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        alert("Window is now open.");
    });
    return self; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josiah :) Didn't have a clue about the open listener. Think I going to study the docs a bit more before I ask here. Still feel their is a lot missing in the docs though! Marked as answer :)